# FastAPI Docs with Bearer authorization for all routes

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I am using fastAPI and I want all my routes, on the /docs to require/pass a bearer token.

One of the ways to do that I found it here: [How to Pass Authorization Header from Swagger Doc in Python Fast API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926257/how-to-pass-authorization-header-from-swagger-doc-in-python-fast-api)

I am currently using this:

```
@router.get("/", dependencies=[my_dependencies])
def read_users(authorization: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(HTTPBearer()), ...rest of the code)
```

The above works, I get the authorization button on my docs, which I set my Bearer Token. I then click on my endpoint try out button, then the execute and the request is ran with the token and everything is beautiful.

Thing is, I don't want to "pollute" every single of my routes with that authorization boiler plate.

What I want to know is if there is a way to set that on the router level

Something like

```
from fastapi import APIRouter 
api_router = APIRouter('STUFF IN HERE')
api_router.include_router(user_controller.router, prefix="/users", tags=["users"], 'OR MAYBE IN HERE)
```

That way I wouldn't need to declare it for every single function. I am not very familiar with Python and haven't had luck finding a solution, hope that the framework support this scenario.

UPDATE:

I did this change:

```
authorization: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(HTTPBearer())
api_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[authorization])


# Included routes for the application.
api_router.include_router(user_controller.router, prefix="/users", tags=["users"])
```

Maybe I should've mentioned that I am starting with Python. Nonetheless while the above works, PyCharm has a warning on the second line that says:

> Expected type 'Sequence[Depends] | None', got
> 'list[HTTPAuthorizationCredentials]' instead

In Typescript strict that seems the kind of thing that would prevent build. Probably, again, I am making a syntax error.

Comment: Have you read through [the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#another-module-with-apirouter)? It appears to directly address this question.

Comment: I already know how to declare dependencies using `from fastapi import APIRouter`, what I am failing to achieve is how the syntax to set `authorization: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(HTTPBearer())` as a dependecy in there. Since the function already does the trick I assume I would not need to create my own custom of it to set into the APIRouter(....).